# Flutter : Several variant outputs are configured to use the same file name

Tags: android, flutter

I am just trying to run the first app and this is what happens:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Several variant outputs are configured to use the same file name "resources-debug.ap_", filters : MAIN:MAIN
```

Comment: You might want to open a new issue on GitHub: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues

Comment: Got resolved using `flutter clean`

Answer (score 26):

Please try `flutter clean` and rebuild.

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error while trying to integrate FCM into my application.. The problem is in the older build file.. i.e as we are editing our Manifest file we need to rebuild the project so..

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```

Make sure to do gradle sync if the problem persist..
It solved the problem for me..

Answer (score 0):

1. `Close and reopen IDE`
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter run`

Comment: This answer does not seem to add information. Months after resolution, it makes one additional suggestion based on the guess that an IDE is used.

Answer (score 0):

just log out from current windows session and then do flutter clean and after run your project. that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If flutter clean doesn't work, then delete the Android folder, then run flutter clean and run the app... Make sure you have an android emulator or device connected as your run device, this will bring a prompt asking you to enable android for your project then just click yes.

You can also uninstall the app from your emulator or android device before you run it again, but make sure its uninstalled on all profiles of your device.

Answer (score 0):

this error also appear when you mistakly disable the app and try to debug same app again.So go to applications and enable it again to resolve the issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. `remove pubspec.lock`
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter run`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are several variant outputs that are configured to use the same file name. To resolve this issue, you could try renaming the output files for each variant to avoid conflicts. You can also update the build variant filter configuration to ensure that each variant has a unique output file name.

```
android {
   ...
   buildTypes {
      debug {
         ...
         applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFileName = "resources-${variant.name}.ap_"
            }
         }
      }
      release {
        ...
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFileName = "resources-${variant.name}.ap_"
            }
        }
      }
   }
}
```